# Cannot read property 'path' of undefined from a custom input file in Bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, express, input, bootstrap-4

I have a form and it has a custom input group that is going to select a local image file. However, I cannot get the file name back in the server code. I've looked into the req.body, but I couldn't find any property that holds the path location of the image file.

I have also tried req.file.path but with no luck.
I'm using bodyParser as my middleware.

```
                   <form action="/campgrounds" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="input-group mb-3">
                                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                    <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroupFileAddon01">Upload</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="custom-file">
                                    <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="inputGroupFile01" aria-describedby="inputGroupFileAddon01" accept="image/*">
                                    <label class="custom-file-label" for="inputGroupFile01">Choose file</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>       
                   </form>
```

Does anyone know how do I get the file name ?

Thanks

Comment: what middle ware are you using for multipart/form-data?

Comment: @SrikanthChekuri: I am using body parser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The body-parser module only handles JSON and urlencoded form submissions, not multipart (which is the case if you're uploading files). For multipart, you'd need to use something like [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer).

https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer

Comment: If I just use the plain standard input type from bootstrap, it works by just calling req.file.path

```
<input type="file" name="myFile">
```
While it does not work in this case here, a custom input file, is still puzzle me.